# InvalidCastException in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio

It looks like things were starting to take shape in my code but I got this message:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Iteration2 V3.exe
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Drawing.Image]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image[]'.**

I was calling 'imgs' from a sub routine

**Private Sub Board1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

~insert rest of code here~

NewGame(imgs)

End Sub**

**Private imgs = New List(Of Image) From {My.Resources.Image_1, My.Resources.Image_2, My.Resources.Image_3, My.Resources.Image_4, My.Resources.Image_5, My.Resources.Image_6, My.Resources.Image_7, My.Resources.Image_8,
    My.Resources.Image_9, My.Resources.Image_10, My.Resources.Image_11, My.Resources.Image_12, My.Resources.Image_13, My.Resources.Image_14, My.Resources.Image_15, My.Resources.Image_16, My.Resources.Image_17, My.Resources.Image_18, My.Resources.Image_19, My.Resources.Image_20, My.Resources.Image_21,
    My.Resources.Image_22, My.Resources.Image_23, My.Resources.Image_24}**

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well the error pretty much says it.  You're trying to cast an list to an array somewhere and that isn't valid.  You can convert an list to array by calling `.ToArray()` if you add `import System.Linq` to the top of your file.  We need to see more code to find where this applies to your situation though.

Comment: @JamesFaix ahh thank you so much!!!!